# Vim highlighting things in red

Tags: vim, vi

Vim is highlighted the first few characters of every line. I've tried everything to fix it that I could find. How can I fix this?

Comment: What filetype ? (type `:set filetype` to see what vim has detected)

Comment: @Tim [Fountain](http://www.github.com/vim-scripts/Fountain.vim/) and anything without a filetype. I'm trying to make screencasts and I'm using Fountain to script them.

Comment: When you `:split`, is the highlighting also in the new window?

Comment: Not really sure, you can try typing `:noh` incase you accidentally started a search that matches the start of a line. Other than that a screenshot may help us to see exactly what it's doing.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Yep. I looked at the source code for Fountain.vim, nothing unusal that might cause this.

Comment: @Tim I said I tried everything i could think of, I did that.

Comment: Well maybe you could say exactly what you tried then. Noone here has any idea how much vim experience you have. You could be a complete beginner for which 'tried everything I could think of' means 'tried nothing', or you could be an expert. Give us something to work with.

Comment: @Tim Sorry. [Here's a screenshot](http://imgur.com/tSaPbpE).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: the filetype wasn't setting properly. Still, this shouldn't happen on empty filetypes.